# gRPC how to set timeout between two messages in a stream

Tags: java, grpc

When I have a streaming RPC (be it client-side or server-side or bidirectional streaming), if I want to monitor if my stream is still active, by setting a timeout between two messages, how do I achieve that? (Java is preferred as gRPC APIs are quite different between languages) Thanks in advance!

Edit: Added explanation on "timeout between two messages".

What I imagine for "timeout between two messages" is like this. The client receives a stream of messages from the server, and the client does not know when the stream is expected to end (the server completes the stream). For example the server streams back S1,S2,S3,S4...S10 back to the client. If the server is somehow stuck before sending S5, the client will "time out" after receiving S4. Note that it's not the timeout for the whole stream to complete, but the timeout between message Si and S(i+1) (between every two messages in a stream.

Comment: not really sure about it, but maybe it is possible to create a context with a deadline for each message, or something: try looking at the javadoc: https://grpc.github.io/grpc-java/javadoc/io/grpc/Context.html . Oherwise you will probably have to implement it completely manually using some background timer thread etc...

Comment: What do you mean "a timeout between two messages" ? Is that where the peer should expect the next message within the timeout or is that a timeout on the client side to expect a "response message" within the timeout? You can use `ServerCall.Listener` to receive events for the call i.e. the stream

Comment: @SanP Sorry about the late reply. I edited my question to better answer this.

Comment: See https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/issues/4814 and https://gist.github.com/jhaber/65eb9fc78413a419c3341b64db4fa2e9 for an implementation of this.